# Hive: Specifying a different format for partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know that it is possible to have one inputformat at the table level and another at the partition level (mixed formats table) but I can't see anything in the docs stating how to accomplish that.
I tried that following statement but it failed:

```
hive> alter table test_tbl_parquet add partition (year=2016,month=01,day=27)
    >  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
    > STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    >   'com.mycopmany.hive.WhaleAvroGenericInputFormat'
    > OUTPUTFORMAT
    >   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    >  location '/mycopmany/data/test_tbl/year=2016/month=01/day=27';
FAILED: ParseException line 1:90 missing EOF at 'ROW' near ')'
```

Any ideas what is the correct syntax?

Thank you.
Daniel

Comment: Try changing the first line to `alter table test_tbl_parquet add partition (dateCol='2016-01-27')`, where `dateCol` is the name of your partition column

Comment: how is that relevant to my question ?

Comment: I think the way your partition clause is specified is causing the problem and the comment I made indicates that.. hopefully this comment clarifies..

Comment: I have three partitions columns. I can't just make up another column that includes them all.

Comment: In that case, have you tried adding quotes around your partition column values like - `add partition (year='2016',month='01',day='27')`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterEitherTableorPartition
Documentation, it describes different file format for a partition.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for a way to specify the format via the ADD partition operation but given that I won't find a way I'll use the ALTER partition operation